# Connecting to proxy/VPN via phantomjs

Tags: proxy, phantomjs, vpn

I'm trying to connect to a VPN via phantomjs. It does not seem to work when I render a page it is blank this is the command:

phantomjs --proxy-type=http --proxy=83.170.84.216 --proxy-auth=freevpnaccess.com:3071 test.js

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VPN is not a proxy. So, PhantomJS cannot use a VPN directly. Establish the connection with the tools that your operating system gives you, and simply run your PhantomJS script without any configuration.

Comment: So basically I should just connect to VPN and use PhantomJS regularly? Tnx mate.